# Given camera matrices, how to find point correspondances using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, surf

I'm following [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html), which uses Features2D + Homography. If I have known camera matrix for each image, how can I optimize the result? I tried some images, but it didn't work well.

//Edit
After reading some materials, I think I should rectify two image first. But the rectification is not perfect, so a vertical line on image 1 correspond a vertical band on image 2 generally. Are there any good algorithms?

[image: first image] [image: second image]
[image: rectification image]

Comment: can you please post the camera matrices for both of your images?

Comment: I didn't compute these camera matrices, a fundamental matrix would be enough, right? Although I didn't compute the fundamental matrix for it either.@Micka

Comment: I thought you did have the camera intrinsics and extrinsics and asked how to use them to improve your result. How did you compute the rectification?

Comment: I have a chessboard, so I can use `findChessboardCorners`, `stereoRectifyUncalibrated`, and `undistort` conveniently. @Micka

Comment: so the camera system is fixed (including zoom/focus)? did you undistort the lenses?

Comment: The camera system is not fixed. I haven't undistorted the lenses, since it is not obvious and most importantly, I don't really understand those methods.@Micka

Comment: Not sure, but looks similar to panoramic view problem. There they use RANSAC algorithm to find the best correspondences between corner points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem. You want to find corresponding points between the images or you want to improve the correctness of your matches by use of the camera intrinsics?

In principle, in order to use camera geometry for finding matches, you would need the fundamental or essential matrix, depending on wether you know the camera intrinsics (i.e. calibrated camera). That means, you would need an estimate for the relative rotation and translation of the camera. Then, by computing the epipolar lines corresponding to the features found in one image, you would need to search along those lines in the second image to find the best match. However, I think it would be better to simply rely on automatic feature matching. Given the fundamental/essential matrix, you could try your luck with [`correctMatches`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#correctmatches), which will move the correspondences such that the reprojection error is minimised.

**Tips for better matches**

To increase the stability and saliency of automatic matches, it usually pays to

- Adjust the parameters of the feature detector
- Try different detection algorithms
- Perform a ratio test to filter out those keypoints which have a very similar second-best match and are therefore unstable. This is done like this:

  ```
  Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2; // obtained from feature detector
  BFMatcher matcher;
  vector<DMatch> matches;
  matcher = BFMatcher(NORM_L2, false); // norm depends on feature detector
  vector<vector<DMatch>> match_candidates;
  const float ratio = 0.8; // or something
  matcher.knnMatch(descriptors_1, descriptors_2, match_candidates, 2);
  for (int i = 0; i < match_candidates.size(); i++)
  {
     if (match_candidates[i][0].distance < ratio * match_candidates[i][1].distance)
        matches.push_back(match_candidates[i][0]);
  }
  ```
- A more involved way of filtering would be to compute the reprojection error for each keypoint in the first frame. This means to compute the corresponding epipolar line in the second image and then checking how far its supposed matching point is away from that line. Throwing away those points whose distance exceeds some threshold would remove the matches which are incompatible with the epiploar geometry (which I assume would be known). Computing the error can be done like this (I honestly do not remember where I took this code from and I may have modified it a bit, also the SO editor is buggy when code is inside lists, sorry for the bad formatting):

  ```
  double computeReprojectionError(vector& imgpts1, vector& imgpts2, Mat& inlier_mask, const Mat& F)
  {
  double err = 0;
  vector lines[2];
  int npt = sum(inlier_mask)[0];
  ```

  // strip outliers so validation is constrained to the correspondences
  // which were used to estimate F
  vector imgpts1_copy(npt), 
    imgpts2_copy(npt);
  int c = 0;
  for (int k = 0; k < inlier_mask.size().height; k++) 
  {
    if (inlier_mask.at(0,k) == 1) 
    {
       imgpts1_copy[c] = imgpts1[k];
       imgpts2_copy[c] = imgpts2[k];
       c++;
    } 
  }

  Mat imgpt[2] = { Mat(imgpts1_copy), Mat(imgpts2_copy) };
  computeCorrespondEpilines(imgpt[0], 1, F, lines[0]);
  computeCorrespondEpilines(imgpt[1](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#correctmatches), 2, F, lines[1](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#correctmatches));
  for(int j = 0; j < npt; j++ )
  {
    // error is computed as the distance between a point u_l = (x,y) and the epipolar line of its corresponding point u_r in the second image plus the reverse, so errij = d(u_l, F^T * u_r) + d(u_r, F*u_l)
    Point2f u_l = imgpts1_copy[j], // for the purpose of this function, we imagine imgpts1 to be the "left" image and imgpts2 the "right" one. Doesn't make a difference
            u_r = imgpts2_copy[j];
    float a2 = lines[1](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#correctmatches)[j][0], // epipolar line
          b2 = lines[1](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#correctmatches)[j][1](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#correctmatches),
          c2 = lines[1](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#correctmatches)[j][2];
    float norm_factor2 = sqrt(pow(a2, 2) + pow(b2, 2));
    float a1 = lines[0][j][0],
          b1 = lines[0][j][1](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#correctmatches),
          c1 = lines[0][j][2];
    float norm_factor1 = sqrt(pow(a1, 2) + pow(b1, 2));

  double errij =
       fabs(u_l.x * a2 + u_l.y * b2 + c2) / norm_factor2 +
       fabs(u_r.x * a1 + u_r.y * b1 + c1) / norm_factor1; // distance of (x,y) to line (a,b,c) = ax + by + c / (a^2 + b^2)
    err += errij; // at this point, apply threshold and mark bad matches
  }

  return err / npt;
  }
   The point is, grab the fundamental matrix, use it to compute epilines for all the points and then compute the distance (the lines are given in a parametric form so you need to do some algebra to get the distance). 
  This is somewhat similar in outcome to what `findFundamentalMat` with the RANSAC method does. It returns a mask wherein for each match there is either a `1`, meaning that it was used to estimate the matrix, or a `0` if it was thrown out. But estimating the fundamental Matrix like this will probably be less accurate than using chessboards.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to find corresponding points between the images. And `SurfFeatureDetector` is not working well in my case, so I want to improve the correctness by use of fundamental matrix.

Comment: @Zen But I fail to see how you can obtain the fundamental matrix without having reliable correspondences first. Maybe for such a small motion between the images you could try optical flow.

Comment: I can take put a chessboard near the dog, from which I can get a fundamental matrix. But I don't know what I can do with the fundamental matrix to optimize matching algorithm such as `FlannBasedMatcher`.

Comment: @Zen I updated the answer with an idea of how to use the fundamental matrix, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Looks like [oarfish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2397253/oarfish) beat me to it, but I'll leave this here.

The fundamental matrix (F) defines a mapping from a point in the left image to a line in the right image on which the corresponding point must lie, assuming perfect calibration. This is the epipolar line, i.e. the line though the point in the left image and the two epipoles of the stereo camera pair. For references, see [these lecture notes](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/OWENS/LECT10/node3.html) and [this chapter](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjM4pebnNzLAhVB7mMKHYAzB58QFggvMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.robots.ox.ac.uk%2F~vgg%2Fhzbook%2Fhzbook2%2FHZepipolar.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGtn62kAjGnssPKQUcShOKvQoHsTQ) of the HZ book.

Given a set of point correspondences in the left and right images: (p_L, p_R), from SURF (or any other feature matcher), and given F, the constraint from epipolar geometry of the stereo pair says that p_R should lie on the epipolar line projected by p_L onto the right image, i.e.

[image: {p_L}^T \cdot F \cdot {p_R} = 0]

In practice, calibration errors from noise as well as erroneous feature matches lead to a non-zero value.

However, using this idea, you can then perform outlier removal by rejecting those feature matches for which this equation is greater than a certain threshold value, i.e. reject (p_L, p_R) if and only if:

[image: {p_L}^T \cdot F \cdot {p_R} > threshold]

When selecting this threshold, keep in mind that it is the distance in image space of a point from an epipolar line that you are willing to tolerate, which in some sense is your epipolar error tolerance.

**Degenerate case:** To visually imagine what this means, let us assume that the stereo pair differ only in a pure X-translation. Then the epipolar lines are horizontal. This means that you can connect the feature matched point pairs by a line and reject those pairs whose line slope is not close to zero. The equation above is a generalization of this idea to arbitrary stereo rotation and translation, which is accounted for by the matrix F.

**Your specific images:** It looks like your feature matches are sparse. I suggest instead to use a dense feature matching approach so that after outlier removal, you are still left with a sufficient number of good-quality matches. I'm not sure which dense feature matcher is already implemented in OpenCV, but I suggest starting [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#densefeaturedetector).

Answer (score 0):

Giving your pictures, your are trying to do a stereo matching.

This [page](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) will be helpfull. The rectification you want can be done using **stereoCalibrate** then **stereoRectify**.

The result (from the doc):
[image: stereoRectify]

Comment: I know how to apply stereoRectify, but I don't know how to find point correspondances after image rectifications. BTW, do you know what are requirements of 6 3d-points to be used to compute the camera matrix? No 4 points on the same plane?

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the Fundamental Matrix, you need correct correspondances, but in order to get good correspondances, you need a good estimate of the fundamental matrix. This might sound like an impossible chicken-and-the-egg-problem, but there is well established methods to do this; RANSAC.

It randomly selects a small set of correspondances, uses those to calculate a fundamental matrix (using the 7 or 8 point algorithm) and then tests how many of the other correspondences that comply with this matrix (using the method described by scribbleink for measuring the distance between point and epipolar line). It keeps testing new combinations of correspondances for a certain number of iterations and selects the one with the most inliers.

This is already implemented in OpenCV as cv::findFundamentalMat (http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findfundamentalmat). Select the method CV_FM_RANSAC to use ransac to remove bad correspondances. It will output a list of all the inlier correspondances.

The requirement for this is that all the points does not lie on the same plane.